# Cannot export Android application with error Failed to export application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Why can't I export my app? and what does this stack trace indicate?

I have seen other people post similar problems(See stack trace) when exporting but the answers given to them did not help me.

I have tried using java 6, java 7, upgrading eclipse, upgrading ADT with no luck.

I am planning to answer this problem myself once the waiting period is up.

Stack Trace:

```
Command-line Error -1073741819
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeAapt(BuildHelper.java:973)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.updateCrunchCache(BuildHelper.java:192)   
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:158)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper$2.run(ExportHelper.java:373)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Session Data:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.7.0_60
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64
```

I found my solution using using Windows 7 with eclipse 4.3 and ADT to Version 23.0.1.1256982.

The solution I found was I had a bad 9-patch image. After ensuring the scaled down versions in the mdpi and hdpi folder were proper 9-patch images the project exported properly.

Really annoying how it fails during the crunching of resources with no indication that it was caused by a bad 9-patch image. You would think running lint would detect things like this and not just failed when exporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution using using Windows 7 with eclipse 4.3 and ADT to Version 23.0.1.1256982.

The solution I found was I had a bad 9-patch image. After ensuring the scaled down versions in the mdpi and hdpi folder were proper 9-patch images the project exported properly.

Really annoying how it fails during the crunching of resources with no indication that it was caused by a bad 9-patch image. You would think running lint would detect things like this and not just failed when exporting.